# Concatenar string com vetor de inteiros e gravar em arquivo?

Tags: c, string, arquivo

Tenho um vetor dinâmico de inteiros. Por exemplo:

```
1 2 4 6 8 9 10
```

Quero uni-lo a uma string, como esta, por exemplo:

```
[B]:
```

E gravar isso em uma linha do arquivo, para depois ler o arquivo com a seguinte saída, por exemplo, supondo que o programa foi rodado três vezes:

```
[B]: 1 2 4 6 8 9 10
[B]: 4 5 6 7 8
[B]: 3 6 7
```

Andei pesquisando, mas não consegui nem ter a ideia de como fazer, por isso, não tenho nenhum código que esteja no caminho de fazer isso.

Alguém pode me dar ao menos um caminho pra fazer isso? Se tem algum comando, uma demostração, ou sei lá.

Comment: `fprintf(arquivo, "[B]:"); for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) fprintf(arquivo, " %d", vetor[k]); fprintf(arquivo, "\n");`

Comment: Vamos eliminar o vetor dinamico por enquanto. Você já consegue criar um arquivo e escrever qualquer coisa estática dentro dele? Pergunto isso, pois você pode dividir o seu problema em partes. Primeiro entenda como abrir, escrever e fechar um arquivo. Feito isso, você parte para a 2a etapa, que é escrever o vetor dinamico. Posso afirmar que se você fizer a 1a parte, a 2a vai ser trivial.

Comment: O que @pmg funcionou perfeitamente. Sim eu sei o básico do arquivo, não estava lembrado do `fprintf` e pensei que poderia ter outra forma.

Comment: @pmg Será que não tem como colocar como resposta? Assim a gente pode votar e a resposta pode ser aceita. Com isso poderemos documentar a pergunta de uma forma mais clara. Obrigado!!! Ah, coloca uma explicação no código em forma de comentário, caso, você aceite minha proposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisas de construir a string dinamicamente em memória: podes usar [`fprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) e imprimir directamente para o arquivo

```
fprintf(arquivo, "[B]:");              // [B]:
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    fprintf(arquivo, " %d", vetor[k]); // 4 5 6 7 8 ...
}
fprintf(arquivo, "\n");                // newline
```

Se efectivamente queres construir a string dinamicamente, usa `snprintf()` (C99) para calcular o espaço necessário.

```
char *result;
size_t bytesneeded = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) bytesneeded += snprintf(0, 0, " %d", vetor[k]);
result = malloc(bytesneeded + 5 + 1); // espaco para "[B]:\n" e '\0'
if (!result) /* erro */;
int count = sprintf(result, "[B]:");
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) count += sprintf(result + count, " %d", vetor[k]);
sprintf(result + count, "\n");

/* usa result, por exemplo fprintf(arquivo, "%s", result); */

free(result);
```